# How to create the dependency path in server while deployment of a project?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, war

After building up my war project size is 26.3MB. It is consuming lot of time to deploy in client server. As,my manager gave a task to me read the dependency from the specified path.

Comment: What do you mean by "read from specified path"? War files are usually self-contained and do not read classes "from the outside". Two things to think about: 1. Figure out if you really need all those dependencies in your war, exclude the unnecessary ones. 2. You can think about establishing a REST service that is called by your war. This way you avoid to have a single, large war.

Comment: here  specified path mean path to the server

Comment: First it's simply not a good idea to let us do your work cause your manager has given you a task todo ? Apart from that what do you mean by `consuming a lot of time to deploy in client server`? What does `a lot mean`? seconds minutes hours? Furthermore a 26 MiB file is small...If we are talking about a war file which has a 1 GiB plus...that's different thing...Overall you have simply missed to show what you have tried to so far and simply missed to describe your problem in detail instead of smashing here only a few sentences....

Comment: What you COULD do is to remove libraries from the project, add them to SERVER classpath and then deploy your project. Dependencies will be there @ runtime so it should work

Comment: how could I add up to server path?? could please share me link to me. I dn't know how to  add.